# Extract token from external Idp

Tags: java, angular, keycloak, idp

I desperately looking for the help with keycloak configuration.
I did successfully create a demo app with angular + java/spring boot app.
I successfully added Github as external identity provider and  configured keycloak.
So basically I can authorize in my app and make a API requests to my API backend with valid authentication token. But now I want to call GitHub API with my user (because I auth with github user). I assume that accessToken that I have is keycloak token and not an GitHub token because using it with API calls to GitHub I am getting bad credentials response.

So, my question is how is it possible to obtain token that was issued to keycloak by github in my application?

I stuck with that issue for a week already trying to find any resources on on internet, read lot's of examples and keycloak documentation.

For example i was trying to do as described here:
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#retrieving-external-idp-tokens
but I got cross-origin error since my keycloak runs on 8180 port and my angluar app is in 4200

Thank you!

Comment: Did you choose the option of store token when configuring the IDP?

Comment: Yes, I did. I currently looking into a way of how to map token from idp to claims.

Comment: You want to inject the token as a claim of another token?

Comment: @dreamcrash that is correct. This is what I am trying to achieve. It is a bad way to do? The final goal is anyway to have this "IdP" token always passing to my backend server. I can do it via custom header or as a claim of another token.

Comment: You should use what is described on the documentation that you have linked. Have you try to set the redirect url of the brokering client with "*"?